# How to transform a column of string into columns of a single char? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am dealing with DNA sequencing data, and each column looks something like "ACCGTGC". I would like to transform this into several columns, where each column contains only one char. How to do this in Python pandas?

Comment: Can you please add some sample data as well as show some desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance convert values to lists and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df['col']], index=df.index)
```

If need add to original:

```
df = df.join(df1)
```